# How to backup and restore in Postgres Sql 9.6 on MAC OSX not in Windows

Tags: macos, postgresql, pgadmin

I am new to Mac world trying to take a backup and restore on postgres sql. I have installed the postgresql on mac machine. I have tried to create a file .bash_profile and given the path for postgres "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin" below is command i am trying to run in terminal

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/pg_restore --host "localhost" --port "5432" --username "postgres" --dbname "postgres" /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/my.backup
```

but it somehow not working. While taking a restore of existing table using PG admin 4 i am getting permissions denied

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/aa.backup'
```

Comment: How to check that ? i m using pg admin 4 how can i change user there

Comment: how to run the psql command using postgres user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you're using a user account which is not the owner of the backup file try to change to the postgres user like this

```
$ su postgres
```

then execute the backup command.
 But first you should change the owner of the backup file. Use:

```
 chown postgres /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/aa.backup
```

Comment: here I forgot, you should change the ownership of the backup file. Use: chown postgres /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/aa.backup